# boto3 ignores the basePath parameter when I try to import or update a swagger description to api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I need to import and then update rest-apis via swagger 2.0 definition in aws api-gateway using boto3 (version 1.9.139) in a python 3.7 script. The problem is that api-gateway ignores the base path parameter.

I understand that it is the "default" behavior (from boto3 docs, basePath=ignore). Then regarding the documentation, I need to set basePath=prepend.

My code:

```py
apiClient = boto3.client('apigateway', awsregion)
api_response = apiClient.put_rest_api(
    restApiId= api_id,
    mode='overwrite',
    failOnWarnings=True,
    parameters={
        'basePath': 'prepend',
        'endpointConfigurationTypes': 'REGIONAL'
    },
    body=open('swagger-def.yaml', 'rb').read()
)
```

My basePath in swagger-def.yaml:

```
basePath: /dev/v1
```

The api_response is ok, there are no warnings or errors. The api-gateway is updated succefully, but the basePath is ignored.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameter may be case sensitive. Please try "basepath" as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-import-api-basePath.html)